# collect list of list from a list of list with particular attribute

Tags: python

I have the following list of list

```
A=[[1,2,3],[1,3,7],[1,4,8,10],[4,6,5]]
```

I would like to collect all the list and form new list of list N where I have selected those list having greater than or equal to 7. In this case, I expect my output to be

```
N=[[1,4,8,10],[1,3,7]]
```

The code has passed through the list A and picked out all list having greater than or equal to number 7.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself?  What specific difficulty are you having?

Comment: Also, in your expected output, why does `[1,3,7]` occur _after_ `[1,4,8,10]`, when it occurs _before_ it in the original list?

Comment: I wanted to try using np.where but was not able to figure out how. The answer by @inspectorG4dget is what I wanted.

Comment: @JohnGordon order doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [[1,2,3],[1,3,7],[1,4,8,10],[4,6,5]]
```

**Method 1**

```
answer = []
for L in A:
    for i in L:
        if i >= 7:
            answer.append(L)
            break
```

**Method 2**

```
answer = [L for L in A if any(i>=7 for i in L)]
```